# Не работает проверка на строку JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Самая обычная проверка на строку, но по какой-то причине - не работает.

```
$(document).on("click", ".button-accept", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var contest_login = $(this).data('contestLogin');

    //console.log(contest_login);

    if(contest_login == "true")
    {
        console.log(contest_login);
    }

});
```

HTML

```
<a href="login/auth/" class="button-accept" target="_blank" data-contest-active="{$user_active_valid}" data-contest-login="{$user_login_valid}">Принять участие</a>
```

Вот, собственно и весь код. При клике мы берем дата параметр который имеет значение "true" (это 100%, т.к. я проверял все ни раз и консоль которая выводит эту переменную без проверки - работает отлично (выводит наш true).

Но проверка if на тот-же самый true, просто не работает.

Необязательно делать проверку на "true", тоже самое на любую строку...
Также пытался переменную contest_login сделать глобальной - эффект тот-же.

Comment: @Даниил добавил

Comment: Проверьте ответ ниже. Судя по вашей разметке и коду, вы пытаетесь обратиться к `data-` атрибуту, которого не существует.

Comment: @Даниил да, всё отлично работает. Не могли бы пояснить в чем была проблема?

Comment: @Klimenkomud в том то и дело, что нет. Я написал вверху, без проверки, переменная выдаёт значение. А после проверки на это-же значение - нет.

Comment: @Klimenkomud через attr(). Как написали ответ ниже - всё отлично заработало. А применяя data() - не работает.

Comment: @Даниил хмм странно, я уже давно так обращаюсь к data аттрибутам в html (data-contest-login) в js (contestLogin).

Да и собственно, консоль которая была до проверки, находила значение data параметра. А в проверке уже не работало. Странно. Ладно, ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: @Даниил в том то и дело. Я поэтому и сам впервые в таком замешательстве ) В общем я вытащил значение не через data(), а через простой attr(), как Вы, предложили во втором варианте. Проверка заработала.

Comment: @Даниил я тоже грешу на кеш... Ибо кнопка имеет уникальный класс, как и аттрибут. Нигде нет js ошибок (в консоли), нет пересечений классов и т.д.

Comment: Добавил еще один вариант, с методом .data()

Comment: @Даниил вот, то что я и искал. Переводит data() в строку. Спасибо )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button-accept", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    var contest_login = $(this).data("contest-login");
  
    if(Boolean(contest_login))    {
        console.log(contest_login);
    }else{
        console.log('else');
    }

});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 
<a href="login/auth/" class="button-accept" target="_blank" data-contest-active="true" data-contest-login="true">Принять участие</a>
```

Вариант №2:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button-accept", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
 
    var contest_login = $(this).attr('data-contest-login'); 
      
    if( contest_login === 'data')    {
        console.log("Условие работает: "+contest_login);
    }else{
        console.log('else');
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<a href="login/auth/" class="button-accept" target="_blank" data-contest-active="true" data-contest-login="data">Принять участие</a>
```

Вариант №3:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button-accept", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    var contest_login = $(this).data("contest-login"); 
  
    if( contest_login.toString() == "data")    {
        console.log("Условие работает: "+contest_login);
    }else{
        console.log('else');
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<a href="login/auth/" class="button-accept" target="_blank" data-contest-active="true" data-contest-login="data">Принять участие</a>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо :)